# Python read in file: ERROR: line contains NULL byte

Tags: python, parsing, nmea

I would like to parse an .ubx File(=my input file). This file contains many different NMEA sentences as well as raw receiver data. The output file should just contain informations out of GGA sentences. This works fine as far as the .ubx File does not contain any raw messages. However if it contains raw data 
I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:...myParser.py", line 25, in 
    for row in reader:
Error: line **contains NULL byte**

My code looks like this:

```
    import csv
from datetime import datetime

import math

# adapt this to your file
INPUT_FILENAME = 'Rover.ubx'
OUTPUT_FILENAME = 'out2.csv'

# open the input file in read mode
with open(INPUT_FILENAME, 'r') as input_file:

    # open the output file in write mode
    with open(OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wt') as output_file:

        # create a csv reader object from the input file (nmea files are basically csv)
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)

        # create a csv writer object for the output file
        writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')

        # write the header line to the csv file
        writer.writerow(['Time','Longitude','Latitude','Altitude','Quality','Number of Sat.','HDOP','Geoid seperation','diffAge'])

        # iterate over all the rows in the nmea file
        for row in reader:
                if row[0].startswith('$GNGGA'):

                    time = row[1]

                    # merge the time and date columns into one Python datetime object (usually more convenient than having both separately)
                    date_and_time = datetime.strptime(time, '%H%M%S.%f')

                    date_and_time = date_and_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-6] # 
                    writer.writerow([date_and_time])
```

My .ubx file looks like this:

```
    $GNGSA,A,3,16,25,29,20,31,26,05,21,,,,,1.30,0.70,1.10*10
$GNGSA,A,3,88,79,78,81,82,80,72,,,,,,1.30,0.70,1.10*16
$GPGSV,4,1,13,02,08,040,17,04,,,47,05,18,071,44,09,02,348,24*49
$GPGSV,4,2,13,12,03,118,24,16,12,298,36,20,15,118,30,21,44,179,51*74
$GPGSV,4,3,13,23,06,324,35,25,37,121,47,26,40,299,48,29,60,061,49*73
$GPGSV,4,4,13,31,52,239,51*42
$GLGSV,3,1,10,65,07,076,24,70,01,085,,71,04,342,34,72,13,029,35*64
$GLGSV,3,2,10,78,35,164,41,79,75,214,48,80,34,322,46,81,79,269,49*64
$GLGSV,3,3,10,82,28,235,52,88,39,043,43*6D
$GNGLL,4951.69412,N,00839.03672,E,124610.00,A,D*71
$GNGST,124610.00,12,,,,0.010,0.010,0.010*4B
$GNZDA,124610.00,03,07,2016,00,00*79
µb<    ¸½¸Abð½                  .        SB  éF  é v.¥  #  1   f  =•Iè    ,
Ïÿÿ£Ëÿÿd¡ ¬M    0+ùÿÿ³øÿÿµj    #ª    ² -K*  
   ,¨  ,  éºJU     /)  ++  f  5    .lG  NL  C8G     /{;  „>  é óK       3  —  Bòl  .   "¿  2      bm¡  
  4âH  ÐM  X cRˆ     35  »7  Óo‡ž    "*ßÿÿØÜÿÿUhQ`  
   3ŒðÿÿÂïÿÿþþûù     ÂÈÿÿñÅÿÿJX ES
     $²I  uM  N:w    (YÃÿÿV¿ÿÿ> =ìî     1¥éÿÿèÿÿmk³m     /?ÔÿÿÒÿÿšz+Ú     ­Ïÿÿ6ÍÿÿêwÇ\  ?   ]?  ˜B  Aÿƒ    y µbÐD‹lçtæ@p3,}ßœŒ-vAh
    ¿M"A‚UE   ôû JQý
'wA´üát¸jžAÀ‚"Å     
 )DÂï–ŽtAöÙüñÅ›A|$Å   ôû/ Ìcd§ÇørA†áÃ£ì˜AØY–Ä   ôû1 /Áƒ´zsAc5+_’ô™AìéNÅ  ôû( ¶y(,wvAFøÈV§ƒA˜ÝwE   ôû$ _S R‰wAhÙ]‘ÑëžAÇ9Å      vwAòÜ§sAŒöƒd§Ò™AÜOÄ   ôû3 kœÕ}vA;D.ž‡žAÒûàÄ @ˆ" Ï¬Ÿ   ntAfˆÞ3×šA~Y2E   ôû3 :GVtAæ93l)ÆšAß yE ôû4 Uþy.TwA<âƒ' ¦žAhmëC   ôû" ¯4Çï ›wAþ‰Ì½6ŸAŠû¶D          ~~xI]tA<ÞÿrÁšAmHE   ôû/ ÖÆ@ÈgŸsAXnþ‚†4šA'0tE ôû. ·ÈO:’
sA¢B†i™Aë%
E   ôû/ >Þ,À8vA°‚9êœA>ÇD   ôû, ø(¼+çŠuAÆOÁ ×œAÈÎ†D 
ôû# ¨Ä-_c¯qAuÓ?]> —AÐÐºÃ ôû0 ÆUV¨ØZsA]ðÛñß™AÛ'Å     ôû, ™mv7žqAYÐ:›Ä‘—AdWxD ôû1 ûö>%vA}„
ëV˜A.êbE   

 AÝ$GNRMC,124611.00,A,4951.69413,N,00839.03672,E,0.009,,030716,,,D*62
$GNVTG,,T,,M,0.009,N,0.016,K,D*36
$GNGNS,124611.00,4951.69413,N,00839.03672,E,RR,15,0.70,162.5,47.6,1.0,0000*42
$GNGGA,124611.00,4951.69413,N,00839.03672,E,4,12,0.70,162.5,M,47.6,M,1.0,0000*6A
$GNGSA,A,3,16,25,29,20,31,26,05,21,,,,,1.31,0.70,1.10*11
$GNGSA,A,3,88,79,78,81,82,80,72,,,,,,1.31,0.70,1.10*17
$GPGSV,4,1,13,02,08,040,18,04,,,47,05,18,071,44,09,02,348,21*43
$GPGSV,4,2,13,12,03,118,24,16,
```

I already searched for similar problems. However I was not able to find a solution which workes for me.

I ended up with code like that:

```
import csv

def unfussy_reader(csv_reader):
    while True:
        try:
            yield next(csv_reader)
        except csv.Error:
            # log the problem or whatever
            print("Problem with some row")
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #
    # Generate malformed csv file for
    # demonstration purposes
    #
    with open("temp.csv", "w") as fout:
        fout.write("abc,def\nghi\x00,klm\n123,456")

    #
    # Open the malformed file for reading, fire up a
    # conventional CSV reader over it, wrap that reader
    # in our "unfussy" generator and enumerate over that
    # generator.
    #
        with open("Rover.ubx") as fin:
            reader = unfussy_reader(csv.reader(fin))
            for n, row in enumerate(reader):
                fout.write(row[0])
```

However I was not able to simply write a file containing just all the rows read in with the unfuss_reader wrapper using the above code.

Would be glad if you could help me.

Here is an Image of how the .ubx file looks in notepad++[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKz9z.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure but your file looks pretty binary. You should try to open it as such

```
with open(INPUT_FILENAME, 'rb') as input_file:
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did not open the file with correct coding format.
So the raw message cannot be read correctly.

If it is encoded as UTF8, you need to open the file with coding option:

```
with open(INPUT_FILENAME, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf8') as input_file
```

Comment: tried it: the error says open(...) takes only 3 input arguments at a maximum

Comment: Would you try to use the following line instead?      
with open(INPUT_FILENAME, 'r', encoding='utf8') as input_file

Answer (score 0):

Hey if anyone else has this proglem to read in NMEA sentences of uBlox .ubx files
this pyhton code worked for me:

```
def read_in():
with open('GNGGA.txt', 'w') as GNGGA:
    with open('GNRMC.txt','w') as GNRMC:
        with open('rover.ubx', 'rb') as f:
            for line in f:
                #print line
                if line.startswith('$GNGGA'):
                    #print line
                    GNGGA.write(line)
                if line.startswith('$GNRMC'):
                    GNRMC.write(line)
```

read_in()

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `gnssdump` command line utility which is installed with the [PyGPSClient](https://github.com/semuconsulting/PyGPSClient) and [pygnssutils](https://github.com/semuconsulting/pygnssutils) Python packages.

e.g.

```
gnssdump filename=Rover.ubx msgfilter=GNGGA
```

See `gnssdump -h` for help.

Alternatively if you want a simple Python script you could use the pyubx2 Python package, e.g.

```
from pyubx2 import UBXReader

with open("Rover.ubx", "rb") as stream:

    ubr = UBXReader(stream)
    for (_, parsed_data) in ubr.iterate():
        if parsed_data.identity in ("GNGGA", "GNRMC"):
            print(parsed_data)
```